# click function not working after ajax call replaces contents of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to create a messages widget that opens a message when the user clicks on its div and that gets refreshed every 30 seconds.

The problem is that after the widget gets refreshed the click functionality stops working. I am guessing that it has to do with the fact that the new elements added were not present when the click was set. And I tested it with firebug, if I run the script after the reload it works until the next refresh.

Does anyone know what is the proper way of resetting something like that after an ajax call?

I include my coffeescript code below:

```
refreshPartial = ->
  $.ajax url: "refresh-messages-feed"

$(document).ready ->
  myElem = document.getElementById("messagesFeed")
  setInterval refreshPartial, 30000  if myElem?
  $(".conversation").click ->
    url = "/conversations/small/" + $(this).attr("id")
    console.log url
    $.ajax
      url: url
      cache: false
      success: (html) ->
        $("#conversation").html html
```

Comment: I am sorry, I was not able to find this answer before posting my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".conversation", function(){
     // Your handler code
});
```

This works by listening for the event at a non-changing ancestor element, then applying the jQuery filter to any elements that generated the event, then applying the function to any elements that matched and generated the event.

Note: Use the closest non-changing ancestor for efficiency, or `document` as the fallback. Do not use 'body' as it has some bugs

Comment: Tried a lot of other hacks but this is only worked for me.